# How to read the SQLite file structure in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, sqlite

How to find file structure of sqlite database.Other words, Sqlite database files (not table record) are saved in which file format.I need to open it as file.

Comment: In code on the iPhone? Or opening the file with a program on your PC?

Comment: I'm curious: why? What's the use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution to any question like this is simply to go to the resource documentation. Nobody could possibly answer this question concisely or usefully in this kind of forum.

Please see [File Format for SQLite Databases](http://sqlite.org/fileformat2.html) on the SQLite website ([sqlite.org](http://sqlite.org)).